setTimeout triggered with different delays
Inside a method in an Angular App, I need to invoke a setTimeout to solve some layout issues with a 3rd party UI library:
setStep(): void {
    // This is a workaround to fix the current UI issue.
    setTimeout(() => {
      const items = document.querySelectorAll('content-slider');
      items.forEach((item) => item.layout());
    });

    this.currentStep = step;
    this.isBtnDisabled.set(false);
  }

When the setTimeout callback is called it fixes the UI library glitch.
The problem is that it is invoked with a random delay: e.g. sometimes immediately (as I would expect, of course in an async fashion being allocated in the queue), but sometimes after 10 - 50 secs. In the latter case, the UI updates after the random delay.
I know there are cases when the setTimeout can be further delayed, but none of them is our case. What might cause the callback to be triggered so randomly? It never happened this behavior in other setTimeout usages.

setTimeout will only run, after the synchronous code has completed, so maybe the problem is, lot of code being run or resource intensive code running, that causes this delay, maybe there is a better angular way to solve the UI issue? which does not involve setTimeout!

I was thinking initially that the Browser was somehow busy and thus delaying the callback execution. However, when the method containing the setTimeout is called, that's pretty much the last part of the execution and not much more happens.

As said by Naren Murali, there is no delay executing the settimeout function. After the javascript engine has executed all the synchronous code and any other asynchronous code that was added before you added your timeout, the first thing it will do is execute your timeout function.

There must be code that takes time and forcibly postpones the executing of the timeout function. If you put a console.log before your settimeout, you can at least see when it was added to the queue. You can try to step through the javascript code to see what synchronous functions are taking up that much time.

@Klaassiek probably it is that case. I tried to debug line by line the code, but after some portion of code I cannot "follow" anymore the execution and the Browser debugger simply hangs (I see the "wait for continuing" icon but nothing happens by pressing F8).

I cannot know for sure but very liekly you are not in Angular zone. Check if it is the issue using NgZone.isInAngularZone() and run code in zone using NgZone.run()

Checked and I am in the Angular zone, so it is not this case. Most probably is due to the surrounding code preventing the callback to proceed.
